# Java how to read parameters from both file and cli?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, properties-file

I'm writing a tool in java and I need to provide some parameters that user can set.

I thought it is good to have ability to save all parameters in a file (and just run the .jar) and to alter saved parameters through command line.

So, I need to somehow handle parameters from two sources (priority, validity, etc.). Currently I use Apache.commons.cli to read cli-provided parameters and java.util.Properties for file-provided properties. And then I combine these properties together (and add some defaults if needed). But I don't like the result, it seems over-complicated to me.

So the code is something like this:

```
Properties fromFile = new Properties();
fromFile.load(new FileInputStream("settings.properties"));
cli.Options cliOptions = new cli.Options();
cliOptions.addOption(longName, shortName, hasArg, description);
//add more options
Parser parser = new DefaultParser();
CommandLine fromCli = parser.parse(cliOptions, args);
//at this point I have two different objects with properties I need,
//and I need to get every property from fromCli, check it's not empty,
// if it is, get it from fromFile, etc
```

So the question is: is there any library to handle properties from different sources (cli, file, defaults)? I tried googling, but did not succeed. Sorry if my googling skills are just not enough.

I'd like the code to be something like this:

```
import org.supertools.allPropsLib;
allPropsLib.PropsHandler handler = new allPropsLib.PropsHandler();
handler.addOptions(name, shortName, hasArg, description, defaultsTo);
handler.addSource(allPropsLib.Sources.CLI);
handler.addSource(allPropsLib.Sources.FILE);
handler.addSource(allPropsLib.Sources.DEFAULTS);
handler.setFileSource("filename");
allPropsLib.PropsContainer properties = handler.readAllProps();
// and at this point container should contain properties combined
// maybe there should be some handler function to tell the priorities,
// but I don't need to decide from where each properties should be taken
```

Comment: Can you elaborate and give an example of how you would want it to be used? What's the difference between getting arguments inside java and outside via cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you define the properties, load them into a `java.util.Properties` container regardless of the source. Then call the logic and pass it the container as a parameter.

Comment: Do you mean I should parse cli args by hand and put them to this container?

Comment: You parse them the same as you do now, and add them to a java.util.Properties.